# http call to a https/SSL webservice, safe?

Tags: php, http, ssl, https

If I do an ajax call from a http server to a webserver with SSL, does my server needs SSL too, or only the webservice?

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a `https://...` URL, then yes, your web server (where the request arrives) should support `https` protocol to get the request.